# jQuery select div with ID and class

Tags: jquery, class, html, hide, startswith

I have the following:

```
<article id="post-43" class="like"></article>
<article id="post-56" class="like"></article>
<article id="post-78" class="dislike"></article>
<article id="bob" class="like"></article>
```

I want to hide all the articles that have ID beginning with "post-" that also have the class "like"  using jQuery.

I have tried this:

```
$('#show_likes').on('click', function() {
    $('input[name^="post-"].like').hide();
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Can someone help?

Comment: Just interesting, may be #show_likes => #hide_likes or .hide() => show()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `article` instead of `input`,and `id` instead of `name`:

```
$('article[id^="post-"].like').hide();
```