# Jquery - Ajax load a portion of returned html using load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please I need some help here. I am trying to make some ajax calls to my django server to enable me return a queryset. I believe the call is successful but the problem is in the returned data contains the whole html and I have tried selecting the div of interest to me but it fails every time.

Here is the successful call without div selection:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var review_div = $('#tm-review-rating-star');
    var next = $('#next-page');
    var prev = $('#previous-page');

    next.click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(url)
        console.log(url)
        review_div.load(url);

        return false;
    })
});
```

Once I try to select the div of interest, the call returns an error please can anyone help me the code for the selection attempt is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var review_div = $('#tm-review-rating-star');
    var next = $('#next-page');
    var prev = $('#previous-page');

    next.click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(url)
        console.log(url)
        review_div.load(url + review_div);

        return false;
    })
});
```

Here is the pages html:

```
    {% load static %}
{% load auth_extras %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .tm-nav li a:hover{
            background-color: #b7d8f7 !important; 
                            
          }

          .tm-nav li a{
            color: darkblue !important;
            font-weight: 800; 
            
          }
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{% static '/iconfavs/apple-icon-57x57.png'%}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/icon" href="{% static '/iconfavs/favicon.ico'%}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/styles.css'%}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/slideshow.css'%}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/slideshowadvert.css'%}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{% static '/iconfavs/apple-icon-60x60.png'%}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="{% static '/iconfavs/apple-icon-72x72.png'%}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{% static '/iconfavs/apple-icon-76x76.png'%}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="{% static '/iconfavs/apple-icon-
```

jaas=

Comment: How to select the div: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602870/jquery-select-div-with-id-and-class

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

> #### Loading Page Fragments
>
> ... If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded

If you just want the contents within the `#tm-review-rating-star` element, it sounds like you want something like this

```js
review_div.load(`${this.href} #tm-review-rating-star > *`)
```

The selector `#tm-review-rating-star > *` tells jQuery to get everything inside the `#tm-review-rating-star` element but not the element itself.

Comment: It worked fine. The issue is that the href page number is not updated after the function is called.  
This is the first url it loads ajax.js:10 /?page=2   
the second url should be ajax.js:10 /?page=3 
but it rather stays on ajax.js:10 /?page=2. 
How do I make it to keep updating the number portion of the url to achieve the pagination.

Comment: @prynet At this point, why bother loading the pages via AJAX?

Comment: I needed a way to get latest reviews at some interval of time on the home page and a few other pages without reloading the page at those times. I want to get this to work first before using setInterval() to call the click function automatically. Do you think there is a better way around this? Thanks a lot for your concern.